# Error when using %dopar% instead of %do% in R (package doParallel)

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, xts

I've come up with a strange error.
Suppose I have 10 xts objects in a list called data. I now search for every three combinations using

```
   data_names <- names(data)
   combs <- combn(data_names, 3)
```

My basic goal is to do a PCA on those 1080 triples.
To speed things up I wanted do use the package **doParallel**. So here is the snippet shortened till the point where the error occurs:

```
list <- foreach(i=1:ncol(combs)) %dopar% {
    tmp_triple <- combs[,i]

    p1<-data[tmp_triple[[1]]][[1]]
    p2<-data[tmp_triple[[2]]][[1]]
    p3<-data[tmp_triple[[3]]][[1]]

    data.merge <- merge(p1,p2,p3,all=FALSE)
}
```

Here, the merge function seems to be the problem. The error is

**task 1 failed - "cannot coerce class 'c("xts", "zoo")' into a data.frame"**

However, when changing %dopar% to a normal serial %do% everything works as accepted.

Till now I was not able to find any solution to this problem and I'm not even sure what to look for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A better solution rather than explicitly loading the libraries within the function would be to utilise the **.packages** argument of the foreach() function:

```
list <- foreach(i=1:ncol(combs),.packages=c("xts","zoo")) %dopar% {
    tmp_triple <- combs[,i]

    p1<-data[tmp_triple[[1]]][[1]]
    p2<-data[tmp_triple[[2]]][[1]]
    p3<-data[tmp_triple[[3]]][[1]]

    data.merge <- merge(p1,p2,p3,all=FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! Keeps everything a bit cleaner!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is likely that you haven't called `library(xts)` on each of the workers.  You don't say what backend you're using, so I can't be 100% sure.

If that's the problem, then this code will fix it:

```
list <- foreach(i=1:ncol(combs)) %dopar% {
    library(xts)
    tmp_triple <- combs[,i]

    p1<-data[tmp_triple[[1]]][[1]]
    p2<-data[tmp_triple[[2]]][[1]]
    p3<-data[tmp_triple[[3]]][[1]]

    data.merge <- merge(p1,p2,p3,all=FALSE)
}
```

Comment: And this was it! I didn't realize that I need to call the lib but it makes perfectly sense as it starts different sessions....Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix for problem with foreach %dopar% is to reinstall these packages:

```
install.packages("doSNOW")

install.packages("doParallel") 

install.packages("doMPI")
```

These are responsible for parallelism in R. Bug which existed in old versions of these packages is now removed. It worked in my case.